# invalid command name "tcl_findLibrary"

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I am trying to run a very basic tcl/tk script to make a GUI and I am able to define the window using wm, however when I try to add a button using just "button" it gives me the error "invalid command name "tcl_findLibrary"". Does anyone know what is causing this? I am confident both the tcl and tk are the same version. Someone else suggested that it was a mismatch between versions so I tried having the first line in my script as:

unset env(TCL_LIBRARY)

However this did not change anything. I am writing this script on a piece of hardware that is not my own so I do not have permission to actually change the environment variables. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What version of Tcl/Tk?  What platform?

Comment: Both versions are 8.5.5, and it's running on OpenSuse 11.2

Comment: If it is a "very basic" script, could you just show us that script?

Comment: Sure, right now I'm just doing 

wm geometry . 800x800

As I said the window pops up but it throws the error tcl_findLibrary

Comment: We had some previous inconclusive discussion of this problem at https://www.reddit.com/r/Tcl/comments/67sb0x/invalid_command_name_tcl_findlibrary/

Comment: What is the contents of the global `auto_path` variable?

Comment: the auto_path environment variable is /export/home/sdc/app-defaults/tcl, same as TCL_LIBRARY

Comment: Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

On my Win10 machine I ran into both of these errors:

- Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories ...
- error "invalid command name "tcl_findLibrary""

The steps I ended up taking to resolve it follows.  I don't know if all are needed.

1. Search all init.tcl files for the line "package require -exact Tcl"
   that has the highest 8.5.x number

   2. Copy it into the first directory listed in the error messages
   3. Set the environmental variables TCLLIBPATH and TCL_LIBRARY to 
      the directory where you found the init.tcl file
   4. Reboot

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into both of these errors:

- Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories
- error "invalid command name "tcl_findLibrary""

I addressed the first error by searching for init.tcl file and cut the init.tcl file to the location that the program wants.

I addressed the second error by moving all file in the tcl8.6/library out to the location where you put the init.tcl at.